# SSL invalid certificate exception when using secure.force.com

Tags: integration

I am trying to connect to a custom RestResource via HTTPS. The custom RestResource is available via a Site and is accessed using the Site Guest User. The URL that I am using to access the site is https://companyname.secure.force.com/

When I use the URL ending secure.force.com I get an SSL exception that states
  != <*.eu1.force.com>

If I switch the secure for eu1 then I can get through fine. However this is not something I want to do as it will be beyond our users.

Is there a way I can configure the site to return a certificate for *secure.force.com?

Cheers

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're out of luck with this but I hope you get a good answer. I know on sandboxes the certs are always invalid.

Comment: can you post an example of some code you're using to connect or what the RestResource looks like? The production *.secure.force.com certs are valid. You may have to configure your integration to work with SAN certs, depending on the client you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue which was reproducing only on last version of Google Chrome  32.0.1700.76 m but which wasn't reproducing on old version of Google Chrome 27.0.1453.110 m neither on Opera browser. My page contained as iframe link to another page using insecure http:// while I was requesting the whole page by secure protocol https://. When I changed the inner link to contain https:// the issue was solved.

Hope this would help.